# Как заменить в строке символ на пробел в python?

Tags: python, строки

```
text = "Test~123"

print(text)
```

Выводит:

```
Test~123
```

---

А сделать нужно, чтоб при выводе было `"Test 123"`

Т.е. убрать знак и заменить его на пробел

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
>>> print(text.replace('~', ' '))
```

`Test 123`

Answer (score 3):

Если набрать в Google.com запрос `python string replace`, то мы придем к документу [string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace]](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace).

Ваше решение будет таким `text.replace('~', ' ')`.

Answer (score 1):

Так же можете попробовать регулярные выражение в данном случае оно удаляет все символы кроме букв и цифр

```
import re
rep = re.compile("[^a-zA-Zа-яА-я,\d]")
text = rep.sub(" ", "Test~123")
print(text) # Test 123
```

Comment: `А-я` - опечатка раз, отсутствие `Ёё` - ошибка два.